# Error creating PDF with Zend (fontWithName)

Tags: pdf, zend-framework, zend-pdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF file using Zend but I keep getting errors when trying to set the font.

Here is my code:

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

    $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $font = new Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);

    $page->setFont($font,24)
         ->drawText("Hello world!",72,720);

    $pdf->$page;
    $pdf->save("example.pdf");
```

And this is the error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'fontWithName' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in /Users/pawel/Sites/Zend/application/modules/default/controllers/IndexController.php on line 83
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just remove `new` for the font declaration:

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);

$style = new Zend_Pdf_Style();
$style->setFont($font, 24);
$page->setStyle($style);
```

`fontWithName` is a static function and `Zend_Pdf_Font` is an abstract class.

See the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.usage.html) for example.

There is another problem:
Replace

```
$pdf->$page;
```

by

```
$pdf->pages[] = $page;
```

Comment: I can remove this but how i can define font in setFont ?Can i just type a name of font ?

Comment: Just remove '`new`', not the instruction. I update my answser to be more clear. :)

Comment: Thanks, i will try it tommorow

Comment: It didnt' works well, got error
"Catchable fatal error: Object of class Zend_Pdf_Page could not be converted to string"

Comment: @Paradiso: I update my answer like the documentation's example.

Comment: Same error what we had last time, convert to string

Comment: You're welcome, thank's for your return. Good luck. :)